# Cauchy sequence problem

Tags: cauchy-sequences

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be defined by the recursive formula $a_1 = 1$, $a_{n+1}=\frac{2 + a_n}{1 + a_n}$ for all $n\geqslant 1$. Show that $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Can i share image of my doings???

Comment: Can't you write it?

Comment: You could just describe shortly what you did and tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: a_{n+1} = \frac{2 + a_n} {1 + a_n} 
\implies |a_{n+1} - a_n| = |2 - a_{n+1}a_n |
\implies |a_m - a_n| = |a_m - a{m-1} - a_n| \leqslant |2 - {a_m} {a_{m-1} } |+ |2 - {a_{n-1} {a_n} |

Comment: Sorry i am weak in writing so many tough latex symbols

Comment: Put the code inside `$ $`.

Comment: Really sorry, i cannot write it,

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

You're expected to write the question and what you've tried in LaTex.

Comment: Just give me a clue, not full answer.

Comment: What can't you write? Dollar sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=\frac{2+x}{1+x}$ is a positive and decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.
  The only positive solution of $f(x)=x$ is given by $x=\sqrt{2}$ and
$$\forall x\in\left[1,\frac{3}{2}\right],\qquad \left|f'(x)\right| = \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\leq \frac{1}{4}. $$
By the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) it follows that $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is convergent to $\sqrt{2}$, hence it is a Cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:$$(*) a_{n+1}=1+\dfrac{1}{1+a_n}>1$$
$$|a_{m+1}-a_{n+1}|=|\dfrac{1}{1+a_m}-\dfrac{1}{1+a_n}|=\\
|\dfrac{a_n-a_m}{(1+a_n)(1+a_m)}|$$ now consider (*)
$$|\dfrac{a_n-a_m}{(1+a_n)(1+a_m)}|<|\dfrac{a_n-a_m}{2\times 2}|\\
|a_{m+1}-a_{n+1}|=|\dfrac{a_n-a_m}{(1+a_n)(1+a_m)}|<\dfrac{1}{4}|a_n-a_m|\\ \to \\|a_{m+1}-a_{n+1}|<\dfrac{1}{4}|a_n-a_m|<\dfrac{1}{4^2}|a_{n-1}-a_{m-1}|\\<\dfrac{1}{4^3}|a_{n-2}-a_{m-2}|<...<\epsilon$$

Comment: Many many thanks sir

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+1}-\sqrt2=\frac{(\sqrt2-1)(\sqrt2-a_n)}{a_n+1}.$$
Thus, $$\left|a_{n+1}-\sqrt2\right|=\frac{\sqrt2-1}{1+a_n}\cdot|a_n-\sqrt2|\leq(\sqrt2-1)|a_n-\sqrt2|,$$
which says that your sequence  converges to $\sqrt2$ and from here it's the Cauchy sequence.